# Nginx With Golang CLI/API tool

Tags: go, nginx, ssl, https

I've poured over countless articles online to try to make this work and I'm not able to. I have written a CLI tool in GO and an API server that accepts an HTTPs PUT method call from the CLI and returns values. All data in the request and response are in JSON format. Everything works when the client communicates directly with the API server and I even have it working through Squid in pass-through mode. I am reworking the API server and client to use secure websockets and I found that the way I currently have Squid configured isn't working. So I thought I'd try Nginx instead, since I found an article on proxying ws socket connections using it on IBM's website. Alas, I cannot get simple https working at the moment. I have created a certificate and key pair and they are signed by a parent certificate. In my GO client code I load a new Certificate Pool with the CA certs from the machine and append my self signed CA cert to the CA pool. This is working currently with Squid pass through. When I try to run my client through Nginx though, it doesn't. I modified my GO code to output the request information it is sending to Nginx and when I watch the NGinx logs I see the client connect and the errors shown below. I never see a connection from Nginx to the API server. Also, I'm not doing SSL termination on the Nginx server and I'd have to do a fair bit of code rewriting to make the API server non-SSL to accommodate that.

Here's the Request info my client sends to Nginx:

```
mycommand single_value
Error: Cannot communicate with API server: Put "https://my_api_server.local:443/uri": Bad Request
REQ HEADERS:
map[Content-Type:[application/json]]
REQ METHOD:
PUT
REQ BODY:
{{"key1":"val1","key2":val2,"key3":val3,"key4":val4}}
```

The entry I see in the Nginx Access Log is:

```
28/Dec/2021:15:19:37 -0800 172.16.150.1 "CONNECT my_api_server.local:443 HTTP/1.1" - https://my_api_server.local- -" TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 400 173 "-" "-" "-"
```

The entry for the request in the error log in debug mode shows:

```
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: epoll: fd:8 ev:0001 d:00007FD46336E010
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: accept on 172.16.150.132:443, ready: 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: posix_memalign: 0000557BECD3F1B0:512 @16
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 accept: 172.16.150.1:54656 fd:9
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 event timer add: 9: 60000:22007365
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 reusable connection: 1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 epoll add event: fd:9 op:1 ev:80002001
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: timer delta: 536667
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: worker cycle
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: epoll timer: 60000
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: epoll: fd:9 ev:0001 d:00007FD46336E1E1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http check ssl handshake
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http recv(): 1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 https ssl handshake: 0x16
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 tcp_nodelay
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL server name: "https://my_api_server.local:443"
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL_get_error: 2
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 reusable connection: 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: timer delta: 2
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: worker cycle
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: epoll timer: 59998
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: epoll: fd:9 ev:0001 d:00007FD46336E1E1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL handshake handler: 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL: TLSv1.3, cipher: "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLSv1.3 Kx=any Au=any Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD"
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 reusable connection: 1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http wait request handler
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 malloc: 0000557BECD3F3C0:1024
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL_read: 127
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL_read: -1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL_get_error: 2
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 reusable connection: 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 posix_memalign: 0000557BECCE8910:4096 @16
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http process request line
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [info] 3006#0: *2 client sent invalid request while reading client request line, client: 172.16.150.1, server: my_api_server.local, request: "CONNECT my_api_server.local:443 HTTP/1.1"
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http finalize request: 400, "?" a:1, c:1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 event timer del: 9: 22007365
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http special response: 400, "?"
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http set discard body
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 xslt filter header
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.14.1
Date: Tue, 28 Dec 2021 23:19:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 173
Connection: close

2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 write new buf t:1 f:0 0000557BECCE9720, pos 0000557BECCE9720, size: 152 file: 0, size: 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:152
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http output filter "?"
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http copy filter: "?"
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 image filter
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 xslt filter body
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http postpone filter "?" 0000557BECCE98F0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 write old buf t:1 f:0 0000557BECCE9720, pos 0000557BECCE9720, size: 152 file: 0, size: 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 posix_memalign: 0000557BECCD4C70:4096 @16
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 0000557BEBAAB920, size: 120 file: 0, size: 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 0000557BEBAABF00, size: 53 file: 0, size: 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:325
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http write filter limit 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 posix_memalign: 0000557BECD45380:512 @16
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 malloc: 0000557BECE01170:16384
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL buf copy: 152
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL buf copy: 120
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL buf copy: 53
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL to write: 325
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL_write: 325
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http write filter 0000000000000000
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http copy filter: 0 "?"
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http finalize request: 0, "?" a:1, c:1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 event timer add: 9: 5000:21952375
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: timer delta: 8
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: worker cycle
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: epoll timer: 5000
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: epoll: fd:9 ev:2011 d:00007FD46336E1E1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: epoll_wait() error on fd:9 ev:2011
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http lingering close handler
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL_read: 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL_get_error: 6
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 peer shutdown SSL cleanly
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 lingering read: 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http request count:1 blk:0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http close request
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 http log handler
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 free: 0000557BECCE8910, unused: 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 free: 0000557BECCD4C70, unused: 3815
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 close http connection: 9
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 SSL_shutdown: 1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 event timer del: 9: 21952375
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 reusable connection: 0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 free: 0000557BECE01170
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 free: 0000557BECD3F3C0
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 free: 0000557BECD3F1B0, unused: 48
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: *2 free: 0000557BECD45380, unused: 400
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: timer delta: 1
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: worker cycle
2021/12/28 15:19:37 [debug] 3006#0: epoll timer: -1
```

and here's my nginx.conf file:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$time_local $remote_addr "$request" '
                      '$request_method $scheme://$host$request_uri $server_protocol" '
                      '$ssl_protocol $ssl_cipher $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       172.16.150.132:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name  my_api_server.local;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl_certs/my_api_server.local.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl_certs/my_api_server.local.key;
        # ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSV1.2 TLSV1.3;
        ssl_ciphers AESGCM:ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl on;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        # include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            resolver 172.16.150.132;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host: $host;
            proxy_pass https://my_api_server.local:9751;

            # Disable caching
            expires -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Going off of the concept of SSL_Bump in Squid I tried using the same SSL cert and key as the API server in my Nginx config. Is this right? Please tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: Your request body `{{"key1":"val1","key2":val2,"key3":val3,"key4":val4}}` is not JSON. Can you show the request in clear-text?

Comment: Yeah... the output of my request body is just printing the values in the struct that the data is contained in and not doing the proper formatting. The code in question in my  client side tool is performing a proper json.Marshal. I'm just using some debug code: 
 fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "REQ BODY:\n%v\n\n", req.Body)
in the code to see the output without worrying about formatting. My gut tells me there's something going on at the TLS/SSL level here. It all works when there's no proxy server in the middle of the client and server.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered my issue and got everything working. I used PostMan to emulate my client request. I noticed in the Nginx log when I ran the request from PostMan, that Nginx showed the correct Method and URI whereas my client did not.

Before:

```
172.16.150.1 - - [28/Dec/2021:12:28:38 -0800] "CONNECT my_api_server.local:9751 HTTP/1.1" TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 400 173 "-" "-" "-"
```

After:

```
29/Dec/2021:13:17:37 -0800 172.16.150.132 "PUT /uri HTTP/1.1" PUT https://my_proxy_server.local/uri HTTP/1.1" TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 200 9822 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
```

I disabled all the proxy configs for my client and simply told it to make the request to Nginx and everything works now. Something about the way I'm defining my proxy settings in my client is wrong, but since there will always be a proxy server in front of my API server, I can leave that out and just point the client at the Nginx server.

I was also able to confirm that the setup works whether I terminate SSL at the Nginx server or pass it all the way through to my API server.

I need to read through the use of the GO http.ProxyURL functionality and understand it better.